# How to display a textbox in SSRS based on not null value in a column from dataset

Tags: reporting-services, textbox, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

in my SSRS from dataset I get a column called TargetValues.

I need to display a textbox (Seting up the visbility rule) if I have at least one value (Not Null) for this column.

Is there any way to browse through the list and check if I have at least one not null value?

My dataset has 3 columns, Id - indicating the id of the row(int), ActualValue (int) and Target Value (int)

example 1: In this case I need to show the text box

Id    ActaulValue  TargetValue

- 1, 555, Null
- 2, 556, Null
- 3, 557,  75

example 2: In this case I need to hide the text box

Id    ActaulValue  TargetValue

- 1, 555, Null
- 2, 556, Null
- 3, 557,  Null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you require null in your TargetValues? What is the min of the field?

I would look at trying to manipulate the query to make the logic for hiding the text box simpler.

For instance if you won't have negative numbers make the nulls 0 and test the Min() for 0 and use that to show/hide.

Like  =IFF(Min(Fields!TargetValues.Value) = 0,TRUE,FALSE)

Also  =IFF(IsNothing(Sum(Fields!TargetValues.Value)),TRUE,FALSE) might work

Comment: Thanks Mozy. A simple solution but solved my problem. I used =IFF(IsNothing(Sum(Fields!TargetValues.Value)),TRUE,FALSE) might work

Answer (score 0):

Set the below expression in the visibility property of the textbox after making it **Show or Hide based on an expression** - 
`=IIF(IIF( MAX( iif( IsNothing(Fields!TargetValues.Value ), -1, Fields!TargetValues.Value ), "give your dataset name" ) = -1, "Null Values",  FormatNumber(  MAX( iif( IsNothing(Fields!TargetValues.Value ), -1, Fields!TargetValues.Value ), "give your dataset name"),0)) = "Null Values", TRUE, FALSE)`

Edit - Works fine for me, see the screen shot for reference.
[image: SSRS-screenshot]

Comment: I am getting the error that hidden expression for the textbox refers directly to the field 'targetvalue' without specifying dataset aggregate. when the report contains multiple datasets, field reference outside of data region must be contained within aggregate functions which specify a dataset scope.

Comment: provide your dataset and expression details.

Comment: Updated the question with better formatting and explanation for dataset.

Comment: attached screenshot for reference, hope this is what you are looking for.